# plist array null although the plist does contain a string

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, initialization, nsarray, plist

I have a plist file that is copied into the docs dir from the main bundle. If the file exists in the docs already it doesn't copy it over which is how it should work.

The problem I have is when I initialise the plist array either in the appDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching or the rootViewControllers viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear methods.

Now the plist in the mainbundle that gets copied over to the docs dir has one item which is a string

The plist source does contain a string called GBP enclosed in array node which is also correct.

I initialise the plist NSMutableArray like this

```
NSString *rootPath2 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath2 = [rootPath2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"currency.plist"];
theCurrency = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath2];
```

And in the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear I check the array with:

```
NSLog(@"Array contains %@", theCurrency);
```

How is the result null?

Comment: Maybe you could try this in the simulator and see what the file in the documents directory looks like when you open it in the plist editor?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it found the file, the plist ought to be a dictionary. Your array in the plist ought to have a name to identify it, so try something like:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath2];
NSArray *currencyArray = [dict objectForKey:@"CurrencyArrayKey"];
```

Where "CurrencyArrayKey" is the key for your array in your plist.

Answer (score 0):

Check the plist content by opening it as a text file.

Plist created through the visual editor are made by a `dict` containing the rest of the elements (I am not clear if your contains a string or an array with a string).

If you see a dict, then your plist will deserialize correctly to a dictionary, not to an array.

You could also try using:

```
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its ok guys I figured it out it was where i was initialising the array. In the viewdidload I provided perform selector after 0.1 second delay and the selector pointed to a method that contains the initialisation for the plist and the conditions I check for when logging the contents of the array.